# How to properly do background check for future tenant in my own house?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, rent, landlord

I'm renting out a bed room in my own 4-bedroom house. This is the first time I'm being a landlord. How do I do proper background check of new tenants and reduce my risk that the person is a criminal?

Answer (score 7):

I am a realtor. For our rental business, we use a service that offers a background check. It costs us about $25, and it is passed along in the form of an application fee.

I suggest you contact a local real estate agent who you know does rentals. Have a conversation about what you are doing, and see if they will help process the application for you, for a fee of course. If you are truly concerned about your safety (The text you wrote can either read as true concern or sarcasm. Maybe we are really in a wild country?) It's worth even a couple hundred bucks to screen out a potential bad roommate.

Comment: Does https://www.tenantverification.com look good to use?

Comment: Yes, I'm truly concerned about my safety given that I lived most of my life in countries where no regular people is allowed to possess gun.

Answer (score 4):

If you can find a tenant by networking -- co-worker, friend of a friend, etc. -- rather than openly advertising, that often gives you a better pool.

Side advice:  Check what local housing laws apply to renting a room rather than having a housemate. Once you start advertising this you may be subject to fair housing laws, additional code requirements, and so on.

Comment: I currently do not have a support network like that to rely on, unfortuantely.